# Sind »Ausprägung« und »Variante« synonym?

Tags: difference, synonym

Wenn ich verschiedene Arten habe, wie ein Objekt gestaltet sein kann, ist es dann bedeutungsgleich, ob ich von *Ausprägungen* oder *Varianten* spreche?

Oder gibt es die Unterscheidung:

- Ein Objekt kann nur zu genau einer *Variante* gehören
- Ein Objekt kann verschiedene *Ausprägungen* geichzeitig haben

Zum Beispiel:

> - Ein Fahrrad gibt es entweder in der roten Variante oder der blauen Variante, es kann nicht beides sein.
> - Es kann jedoch in den Ausprägungen »mit Rennradlenker« oder »als Damenrad« gestaltet sein.
>     Hierbei kann es mehrere Ausprägungen gleichzeitig haben, z. B: »Damenrad mit Rennradlenker«.

Comment: Bei Fahrrädern würde ich immer von "Variante" sprechen (oder "Modell"), nie von "Ausprägung". Eine Definition, wann man den einen oder den andere Begriff verwenden sollte, kann ich aber auch nicht liefern. Bei Abstrakta scheint "Ausprägung" eher angebracht. Die Bedeutung an sich halte ich für identisch, für eine Hierarchie nimmt man eher "Untervariante" oder so etwas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich würde sie nicht als synonym betrachten.

Eine *Ausprägung* assoziiere ich mit einem *Merkmal* oder *Attribut*.
Im Falle des Beispiels hat das Merkmal *Farbe* die Ausprägung *Blau* oder *Rot*.
Ebenso ist die *Ausführung* (noch so ’n Wort) des Lenkers oder des Rahmens ein Attribut.

Eine *Variante* ist eine konkrete Menge an Merkmalsausprägungen.

Variante 1: ein rotes Damenrad mit Sportlenker

Variante 2: ein rotes Damenrad mit normalem Lenker

Variante 3: etc.

Dieser Sprachgebrauch scheint zumindest konform mit den Artikeln [Mass Customization](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Customization) und [Morphologischer Kasten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphologischer_Kasten) auf Wikipedia zu sein.

> … eine Vielzahl von Ausstattungsvarianten angeboten, aus denen er sich seine Varianten aussuchen kann.

Comment: Diese Unterscheidung klingt gut. Auch die Duden Definition der Wörter _Variante_ und _Ausprägung_ würde dazu passen. `Ausprägung: Ausbildung, Form, Schattierung, Spielart` gegenüber `Variante: leicht veränderte Art, Form von etwas; Abwandlung, Abart, Spielart`

Answer (score 3):

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach sind das absolut keine Synonyme.

Ich betrachte eine Ausprägung von etwas als eine Wandlung vom generischen Konzept (einer nicht notwendigerweise real existierenden "Idee" eines Dings) zum realen Objekt:

*Ein VW Käfer ist die Ausprägung eines Fahrzeugs*

(funktioniert mit "Variante" nicht, da es kein real existierendes generisches Fahrzeug gibt - eben nur *Ausprägungen* davon)

Eine Variante von etwas bewegt sich immer auf der selben konzeptuellen Ebene wie der Ausgangspunkt, der normalerweise ein real existierendes Objekt bezeichnen muss

*Ein Käfer Cabrio ist eine Variante des VW Käfers*

Es mag sein, dass ich hier zu sehr von den Konzepten der Computersprachen "infiziert" bin - Dort werden diese Begriffe exakt so unterschieden

Answer (score 2):

Diese Unterscheidung gibt es nicht.

Es gibt zwar exklusive (rot-blau) und inklusive (Option 1/Option2/Option 3) Alternativen, aber weder "Ausprägung" noch "Variante" impliziert "exklusiv" oder "inklusiv". Ebenso gut könnte man die Farbe eine Ausprägung und das Damenrad eine Variante nennen.